# How do I get a batch file variable assigned to another variable?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code:

```
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%i in (%T1R%.orignal) do (
    set LINE="%%i"
    set LINE1=%LINE%
    echo %LINE1% >> %T1R%
  )
```

Which is producing the following:

```
...
set LINE="    <Reference Include="Elmah">"
set LINE1=
echo   1>>C:\Temp\sync-msbuild-1R.txt
...
```

I've look at other similar questions and it appears that this should work, but it isn't on my system.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly your code is supposed to achieve (why not use `Line`instead of `LINE1` or even better `%%i` directly), but if you want to use variables defined within a loop, you should use [delayed expansion](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Then use `!` instead of `%`:

```
SET LINE1=!LINE!
```

Comment: I need to replace/trim the value that is in %%i. ex. set LINE=%LINE:">=% however, I finding that the variable LINE never gets set. Even after I add the above, it doesn't work on my system. LINE doesn't seem to get the value stored in %%i...

Comment: If I have only one set command, it works. When I have two set commands, it doesn't work...

Comment: That may have something to do with your input containing characters to be escaped such as `<` - try with an input file containing simple text first. As to _two SET commands_, it does work when using delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an answer that would allow me to have two SET commands within the DO block so I ended up solving the question by using PowerShell to accomplish the task:

```
PowerShell -Command "((Get-Content %T1R%) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '""[^\w]*>', ''} | Set-Content %T1R%)"
```